# Find the maximum value of $4x − 3y − 2z$ subject to $2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4z^2 = 1.$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Find the maximum value of $4x − 3y − 2z$ subject to $2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4z^2 = 1.$

My Attempt
let $S=4x − 3y − 2z$ and $ t=2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4z^2$. Then $t-s =2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4z^2 -(4x − 3y − 2z)= 2(x-1)^2 + 3(y+1/2)^2+4(z+1/4)^2 -3>=-3$
so $s<=t+3<=4$ as $t=1$ So minimum value of S is 4.
It my reasoning and answer correct? I am novice in this type of problems and not confident that I have arrived a right solution or not. Please help.

Comment: I find this is the reverse of my problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070626/2x2-3y24z2-1-find-the-maximum-of-4x3y2z?rq=1

Comment: Your approach leads to $s \le 4$ which is indeed true, however $s=4$ is never possible as that would need $x=1, y=-\frac12, z = -\frac14$, which would not satisfy the constraint $t=1$.  As the inequality never gets to be an equality, it remains an upper bound, but not the maximum.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** CS inequality $\implies$
$$(2x^2+3y^2+4z^2)(8+3+1) \ge (4x-3y-2z)^2$$

Comment: According to this , minimum value is $2 \sqrt{3} $ . Can you please point out the mistake in my approach.

Comment: Maximum value is $2\sqrt3$.  You should check that equality is indeed possible in the above CS. Also explained the issue with your approach above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Compute the gradient of $$\vec\nabla S = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial S}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial S}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial S}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}4\\-3\\-2\end{pmatrix} $$

Now find all the points where this gradient is prependicular to your surface defined by $T(x,y,z)= 2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4z^2 = 1$

To do so compute the gradient of your surface function $T$
$$\vec\nabla T(x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}4x\\6y\\8z\end{pmatrix} $$
Then you get $x=\lambda$ $y=-2\lambda$ and $z=-2\lambda$

Find now the two values $\lambda$ such that $T(\lambda)=1$

$$T(\lambda)=2\lambda^2+12\lambda^2+16\lambda^2=30\lambda^2=1$$

This means $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{1/30}$
This leads to $S(\lambda_1)=7\sqrt{\frac{2}{15}}$ and $S(\lambda_2)=-7\sqrt{\frac{2}{15}}$. So have the maximum and minimum of $S(x,y,z)$ while the condition $T(x,y,z)=1$

**[Edit]**

I think I messed up.